# What Z-factor to set in Curvature (spatial analyst)?

Tags: arcmap, spatial-analyst, curvature

I'm making a slope curvature map, my DTM is 5*5 meters cells, in a meter grid projection.
The elevation is in meters asl.
When using the Curvature tool for different units of measure, [the Z-factor has to be set](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000tw000000.htm).

> If the x,y units and z units are in different units of measure, the
>   z-factor must be set to the appropriate factor, or the results will be
>   incorrect. For example, if your z units are feet and your x,y units
>   are meters, you would use a z-factor of 0.3048 to convert your z units
>   from feet to meters (1 foot = 0.3048 meter).

Yet I'm not exactly sure if I need to set a Z-factor of 5, or use the default of 1, because in the "[how curvature works](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/How_Curvature_works/009z000000vs000000/)" page, the illustration shows that the value for "L", is one raster cell (in my case, 5 meters)

What is your opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your x,y and z units are in metres, so set your Z-factor to 1. Metres asl just means that your  z values were determined using an approximate sea level value as a reference point.